# Measuring high voltage with a microcontroller

Tags: adc, power-electronics, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

My goal is to measure 19 volts and 24 volts with the internal ADC.
I am using a BeagleBone Black which has 1.8V analog input pin.  If I use a voltage divider I have to reduce the voltage by a factor of 14 and again multiply with the same in code to get actual voltage. That will multiply the error, too, and that I don't want.

Is there any better alternative? Other than using low tolerance resistors.

Could using an external ADC help here? I have heard of voltage controlled oscillators. Is that useful here?

Comment: No, resistor divider with an opamp buffer is the way to go. There are no perfect error-free measurements."*That will multiply the error too and that I don't want.*" I'm sure you don't, but you aren't very convincing without actually saying how accurate you need it to be or what you are using it for. At least with 0.1% resistors, or better yet a 0.01% TCR matched pair you easily know what the error is

Comment: I know it feels a bit nasty, but differential probes, and even passive probes on oscilloscopes do this too and with much larger ratios (1000).

Comment: Usually the answer to "improving the error" (noise) is to over-sample and average the values.

Comment: Depends what you want to do, Do you really need to measure 0-19V or 0-24V ..or do you need to know the accuracy of the 19 or 24 volt input in absolute terms? In many cases you simply need to know if the supply is within a percentage of its required voltage such as 0.1% and anything outside that range is a fault.

Comment: Going further on what others are getting at: if you don't need full-scale readings, e.g. if you don't care if the 19V input is 7.02 or 7.05V because something is very broken in either case, then you might consider using the voltage divider solutions shown and only amplifying the difference between the reduced voltage and a known, stable reference.

Comment: I want exact voltage as precise I can get, although error below 10mV is tolerable but I don't want to measure range. I have to vary the PWM based on voltage. 0.1% error still tolerable. I have tried voltage divider with resistor array but didn't use opamp will try that and see if it helps.

Comment: If you have two analog inputs, you can use one for coarse measurements and one for fine measurements near the target range.

Comment: As an aside - 19V and 24V are **not** *"high voltage"* - those are solidly in the *low voltage* camp, no matter whose system of high/medium/low you are using (eg: IEC 61140:2016)  By some reckoning these are *not even low voltage*, which commonly starts at the low end of around 50V or 100V, so 19V and 24V would be more properly designated as *"[Extra Low Voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage)"* (ELV - IEC 60038).

Comment: 10mV resolution in 24V is only 2400 steps. Barely half of what a 12-bit converter is capable of. 0.04% steps. So more than a 0.1% resistor but not a 0.01% resistor. And it's not even the actual resistance accuracy that matters but the ratio accuracy in the divider. 0.01% matched pairs are pricey though but still simpler and probably cheaper than other methods like throwing in external ADCs, etc. You can also just trim regular resistors with pots.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4pOQX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistors divider works always exactly the same. For very precise measurement you need a low TCR value resistors. The tolerance doesn't matter if you will insert a calibration factor in the MCU, else you can use 0.1% tol. resistors.

Now, what errors will be amplified? For sure the offset error and temperature drift error. The offset remains unchanged, it's a manufacturing  artifact, while the drift changes, Since the opamp is used as a buffer the output VS input is 1:1.

There are opamps with micro volts of drift.

[image]

This is an overkill for your demand, just for an example. You can see micro volts of offset and nano volts of temp. drift.

Your ADC is 1.8V / 12-bit, therefore a minimum step is approx. 2.4mV.

Much cheaper version:

[image]
[image]

The offset is max- +/- 1 count of ADC. The resistor divider shall output approx 30mV less than 1.8V at maximum range.

EDIT:

Since the offset of 2mV would be multiplied by factor 17 on MCU, then it will happen what you are aware off, so just pick one another opamp, so that the offset multiplied by factor doesn't exceed 1 LSB voltage: 2.4mV/17=140uV

MAX9620AXK+T

[image]

You can search for it: opamp RRIO, supply voltage, offset, ... price. More you pay more accurate you get, until a certain point where ADC accuracy is less than opamp.

Comment: Zero calibration may be an option to compensate the offset error.

Comment: Thank You very much for detailed answer. I lost you in your edited answer. How using second opamp will reduce multiplied factor ?

Comment: @DharmikPrajapati The first will give +/- 1LSB of offset error, then it would translate to +/-17 LSB when multiplied back. The second one has 25uV offset that it can't be detected by ADC. The second one doesn't have the in-built diode protection (not sure, you have to ask the manufacturer).

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, your precision is 12 bit. So, at 24V, 1 step is about 6mV. At 1.8V, it is 0.4mV
The errors come from:

1. Resistor tolerance. This you can calibrate if needed. Else use a matched pair. Eg: Y0115V0522BV0L.
2. Thermal noise in the resistors. Yes, this will be multiplied. Oversampling can help.
3. EMI. I hope you are only needing to measure DC and hence, can apply some combination of L and C filtering and oversample.
4. Temperature variation. If you use a matched pair, this will be ok.
5. ADC error. It is what it is!

With all this, perhaps the error is lower than what you can tolerate?

I dont think you need an OpAmp unless the source is high impedance output and cant drive your voltage divider directly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did considered all points except oversampling. I will surely try that to. I have tried without opamp and didn't get expected result with resistor array like one you mentioned. One side question, can you please explain exactly why we need opamp for high impedance output ?

Comment: Info on the ADC was sparse. I found a note that 1K or less of pulldown is recommended. With the voltage divider I suggested with that in mind, it will draw some 15mA at 24v. If this is a significant current for the voltage source, it may be too much of a load on the source and may drop the voltage some. In that case, you'd have to use a different voltage divider with higher resistances and then use an OpAmp as a 1:1 buffer.

Answer (score 0):

A chopper and low pass filter can precisely attenuate with no tight tolerance components at all. The amount of attenuation is controlled by the duty cycle of the chopper. The oscillator driving the counter that sets the duty cycle can have a very loose tolerance providing it has short-term stability. How it might be implemented depends on your requirements.